# How to overcome the OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android

I am developing an app which gets image urls from server. I have to use that url and set the image background. Every thing is working nice for 15-20 Mins. After that app is crashed.

> 03-06 18:35:43.871: E/GraphicsJNI(22189): VM won't let us allocate 93000 bytes

It is showing this line in the logcat when this error is occured. Any solution ?

Comment: @downvoter, what is the mistake in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you use your `Bitmap`s, you should **`recycle()`** them. Additionally, wrap all your Bitmaps into `WeakReference`s to let the Garbage Collector more easily release resources.

Android applications have a very strict memory limitation which is easily reached when doing gymnastics with `Bitmap`s.

Comment: I have taken images as bitmaps and collected all the bitmaps in a vector. when i move to next activity, i am recycling all the bitmaps in the ondestroy(). Every thing is fine. when i try to come back to previous activity then app is crashed !!  **03-07 11:51:07.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1192): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@4614b760**

Comment: Please tell how to wrap all bitmaps into weakReferences for letting GC easily release resources. Any **code** regarding that ?

Comment: @muralidumpala You can't use Bitmaps you've already recycled. Use `WeakReference<Bitmap>` instead of `Bitmap`.

Comment: Yeah i am trying that using the weak references.  I think GC is not collecting in time. Anyhow thanks for suggestion.

Comment: yeah your suggestion is good, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens because you setting huge pictures to your `ImageView` until the point where your devices runs out of memory.

What you should do is to create a thumbnail version of this pictures and apply them to the `ImageView`. and show the full Image only when this `ImageView` is clicked or not show it at all.

you could use this method to get the thumbnail of the image from file but you have to save the image first on your device to a file object:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) { // BEST QUALITY MATCH

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        }

        int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

        if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
            //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }


    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```

Comment: I have listview which has images in each row. I am taking the Url and then get the bitmap from url and set **bitmap** to the ImageView. It is working fine for 10-20 Mins. Then app is **Crashed**.

Comment: @muralidumpala, I understood your problem... did you read my answer?

Comment: I read your answer. I have scaled the bitmap too. Still app is crashed. I am using the WeakReferences<Bitmap> now.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you dispose correctly and that your not using images that are too large or stay in memory. 
See this documentation by android

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onLowMemory%28%29

You can override the onLowMemory() method to manage your memory usage.

Comment: Hi Niel, thanks for reply.  I think onLowMemory() works only when the device is running outofmemory not for app.